# First Filter then Sort results

Tags: php, sql, sorting, get

I hope you can help me.. My problem is I've got a PHP+SQL script on my website where you can search for Artists, Songs and Stuff. I've got a table with 4 cells: Title, Artist, Genre and Language. And i have configured everything so that it all works if you type in a search query in a  tag.

HTML:

```
        <div class="search_bar">
  <form method="post" action="example.php?go">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Artist, Song, Language or Genre">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <input class="btn btn-default Go" name="submit" type="submit" value="Go!"></butto>
</span>
```

PHP+SQL:

```
         <?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
if(isset($_GET['go'])){
$name=$_POST['name'];
;

//connect to the database
$db=mysql_connect ("example", "example", "example") or die ('Ups! Seems like something went wrong!'); 

//-select the database to use
$mydb=mysql_select_db("example");

//-query the database table
$sql="SELECT * FROM example WHERE Titel LIKE '" . $name . "%' OR Language LIKE '" . $name . "%'  OR Genre LIKE '" . $name . "%' OR Artist LIKE '" . $name . "%'";


//-run the query against the mysql query function
$result=mysql_query($sql);

//-count results


while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
// \(^_^)/
//tabellen beginn ?>

         <tr>
           <td class="col-sm-1"><?php echo $Titel =$row['Titel']; ?></td>
           <td class="col-sm-2"><?php echo $Artist =$row['Artist']; ?></td>
           <td class="col-sm-2"><?php echo $Genre =$row['Genre']; ?></td>
           <td class="col-sm-2"><?php echo $Genre =$row['Language']; ?></td>
         </tr>
         <?php
}
}
else{
echo "<p>Please enter a search query</p>";
}
}
//Suchbareinstellungen_Songs
?>
```

So now to my actual problem: I want the user to have the option to either choose dynamically if he wants to sort the songs, the artist or the language alphabetically. I guess I have to work with a second $_GET superglobal but how do I implent that it just sorts the results which are shown from the search query $_GET Tag.

Greets,
Max

Comment: Hi, you are not protecting your self again sql injections, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php to learn more

Comment: Transition your code to use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead of using `mysql` functions. And as @Kentoro said, you are not protecting yourself against SQL injections. Use prepared statements, which `mysqli` easily enables.

Comment: I would recomment using a ORM, alone or as part of a framework, this is a favorite of mine, is simple to understand and if you scroll done you'll see how easy it is to use order by statements in it: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent

Comment: @Mari M Ooops yea sorry. Just forgot about it caus to hushy....*shame on me*.
OK i will try mysqli thanks and ORM

Comment: Please don't do MySQL queries like this. This can lead to [SQL-Injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Use the PDO extension of PHP if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could dynamically alter your sql depending on the option chosen

pseudo code example incoming:

```
Switch($optionchosen) {
case 1 : $sql = $sql . ' ORDER BY ARTIST';
break;
case 2 : $sql = $sql . ' ORDER BY LANGUAGE';
break;
case 3 : $sql = $sql . ' ORDER BY TITEL';
break;
}
```

and after you have done that perform your

```
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Also just as an extra tip, take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp
to learn about php prepared statements to protect your database from sql injection when you are dynamically creating sql statements

Comment: Make sure you have something in your html like a dropdownlist that has a string as display value but an actual value with an integer value as this slightly increases your processing speed.

Comment: I'm getting off for a while now, heading home from work, so let me know if it worked out for you, I'll be back behind a computer in about 3 hours so if you still need help then let me know